# Change pystray tray notification title

Tags: python, python-3.x, pystray

I have an issue with finding a way to change the **[pystray](https://pystray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)** tray notification title. It appears that it's taking a default value of "Python" from somewhere. See the image below:

[image]

In the [documentation](https://pystray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html), there are no additional parameters to change the notification icon title. How can I find a way to change the title value to something that I want?

Here is a working code example:

```
from tkinter import *

from pystray import MenuItem as item
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

from res import * #here is my base64 encoded icon. Variable icon_base64.
from base64 import b64decode

import pystray
import base64

pic=ImageTk.BytesIO(icon_base64) #transfering base64 to bytes

def run_icon():
    #image = Image.open("icon.ico") #uncomment this to use a standard image, isntead of base64.
    title="Tray title"
    image=Image.open(pic) #comment this if using standard way of image
    menu = (item('test1', lambda: show(),default = True), item('Exit', lambda: exit()))
    global icon
    icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, title, menu)
    icon.run()
    
def show_notification(text):
    icon.notify(text,"My test notification sub title")
def show():
    print("show")
def show():
    print("exit")

run_icon()
sleep(3)
show_notification("test")
```

**Update**: An idea just came to my head - perhaps this "Python" is being taken from the project name or program name, etc. Should I search or add code related to naming parameters (on a Win10 OS)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Python** is an interpreted language, which means that it executes code line by line rather than compiling the entire program into a standalone executable. This means that your program does not have a standalone existence until you compile it. In a Windows environment, the commands you have written are executed by `python.exe`.

To answer your question, in Windows, the title of each notification comes from the value of the `File description` property. In your case, it is "Python" as shown below:"

[image: python.exe properties]

Given this, you need to turn your code into a standalone executable file and fill in some property values. This can be done in two steps:

#### STEP 1

Create a **VSVersionInfo** file (e.g.: `version_info.rs`), with the following indicative content:

```
VSVersionInfo(
    ffi=FixedFileInfo(
        OS=0x4,
        fileType=0x1,
    ),
    kids=[
        StringFileInfo(
            [
                StringTable(
                    u'040904B0',
                    [
                        StringStruct(u'FileDescription', u'Tray Application'),
                        StringStruct(u'InternalName', u'trayapplication'),
                        StringStruct(u'LegalCopyright', u'Copyright (c) Andreas Violaris'),
                        StringStruct(u'OriginalFilename', u'trayapplication.exe'),
                        StringStruct(u'ProductName', u'trayapplication'),
                        StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'1.0')])
                    ]
        ),
        VarFileInfo([VarStruct(u'Translation', [1033, 1200])])
    ]
)
```

##### TL;DR:

The **VSVersionInfo** structure is used to store version information for a Windows executable file. The structure consists of two parts. The "**ffi**" part is a **FixedFileInfo** structure, which stores general information about the file, such as the file type, operating system version, and other attributes. The "**kids**" part is a list of sub-structures that store more specific version information.

##### The "ffi" part of the VSVersionInfo structure contains a FixedFileInfo structure.

- The "**OS**" property specifies the operating system version for which the file was designed. The value `0x4` corresponds to the **Windows NT** operating system.
- The "**fileType**" property specifies the type of file. The value `0x1` corresponds to an application.

##### The "**kids**" part of the **VSVersionInfo** structure contains a list with two elements: a **StringFileInfo** structure and a **VarFileInfo** structure.

- The **StringFileInfo** structure contains a list of **StringStruct** structures that are self-explanatory.
- The **VarFileInfo** structure is used to store information about the language and character set of the file. It consists of a single **VarStruct** structure with the property "**Translation**" and the value `[1033, 1200]`, which corresponds to the English (US) language and the Unicode character set.

#### STEP 2

Turn your program into a standalone executable using a tool like **[PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/)**. To use **PyInstaller**, you first need to install it using a package installer like **pip**:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Then, you can use the following **PyInstaller** command to package your program into an executable and set its version information using the `version_info.rs` file of the first step:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py --version-file version_info.rs
```

#### RESULT

After running the executable (located in the **dist** directory), you will find that the notification title now has the value you assigned to the **FileDescription** property in the first step.

[image: result]